# Group By Having Max

Tags: mysql

This is part of query

```
SELECT 
    `delivery-types`.`delivery-types_name`,
    SUM(CASE `order`.order_status
        WHEN 'fake' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS total,
    MAX(deliverability.delivery_first_week_repo.from_sale) AS top
FROM
    `delivery-types`
        LEFT JOIN
    deliverability.delivery_first_week_repo ON `delivery-types`.`delivery-types_name` = delivery_first_week_repo.type
        INNER JOIN
    order_delivery ON `delivery-types`.`delivery-types_code` = order_delivery.order_delivery_code
        INNER JOIN
    `order` ON order_delivery.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE
    delivery_first_week_repo.week_day = DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE())
        AND order_delivery_code IN ('cream-ec' , 'courier')
        AND order_createdAt >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (7 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY
        AND order_createdAt <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (0 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY
GROUP BY deliverability.delivery_first_week_repo.from_sale
HAVING MAX(deliverability.delivery_first_week_repo.from_sale);
```

And this is result [image: result] I want to see only strings with `delivery_first_week_repo.from_sale`. What is wrong?

Comment: here's part of the answ...

Comment: @Strawberry I think you're giving away too much information.  You should also use a foreign language.

Comment: @Strawberry add code.

Comment: Tip: Don't use reserved words as table/column identifiers - not even in translation. And don't include '-' in table/column identifiers either.

Comment: And finally, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry its not my base

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen add subquery `and from_sale = (select max(from_sale) from deliverability.delivery_first_week_repo)` but there is empty result